# scientific reasons behind a a sudden yet temporary growth sprout of the plant when the soil has No depth?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, growth, soil

Sorry, I'm kind of naive when it comes to plant biology.

> Mark 4:5-6( New American Standard Bible 1995 )
>
> 5 Other seed fell on the rocky ground where it did not have much soil;
> and immediately it sprang up because it had No depth of soil. 6 And
> after the sun had risen, it was scorched; and because it had no root,
> it withered away.

When someone plants in soil with No depth then will the plant immediately spring up( i.e. a sudden yet temporary growth sprout)?  If yes, could someone please explain the scientific reasons behind a a sudden yet temporary growth sprout of the plant when the soil has No depth?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I’m voting to close this question because it is both unclear/unfocused (among other things the type of plant and the environmental conditions will matter) and not well motivated (religious texts are not a good source for biological information). If you wish to ask questions here  please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details of what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a seed would germinate (start to grow) when there is enough damp and warmth beneath the surface of the soil, and the shoot would push upwards at the same time as the root pushes downwards. The root then would be in the moist soil, able to suck-up water when the young plant needs it.

But because there is no depth to the soil, the roots grow and are unable to penetrate the soil and go down, instead they push the body of the seed upwards:

[image: Cress on tissue.]

<sup>Cress seeds grown on tissue. Copyright unknown, [groseeds.co.uk](https://www.groseeds.co.uk/cress-seeds-common-cress/) (commercial) 2022 fair usage.</sup>

The roots and shoots will then dry out.

You can try this at home with cress grown on moist tissue paper.